# APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a vs. generating map files. How in script figure out which build is linked?

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

I have something like this:

```
 <arg value="APP_ABI=armeabi  armeabi-v7a"/>

 <property name="linker.mapfile" value="-Xlinker -Map=@{mapfile}" />

 <arg value="LOCAL_LDFLAGS=@{linkerflags} ${linker.mapfile} />
```

Both map files are generated, however they are saved to this same place  (second map overwrite first). I need to find a way to recognize which build is linked. Which variable should I add to mapfile path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use TARGET_ARCH_ABI for this? That's usually defined per build with the regular Make-based ndk-build. Not sure about the ant syntax, maybe something like this will do it:

```
<property name="linker.mapfile"
   value="-Xlinker -Map=@{mapfile}-${TARGET_ARCH_ABI}" />
```

Comment: Where are these XML properties specified? I am trying to enable map file output myself but not sure how to set it up

Comment: This is in the ant build (check the date - 4 years ago!) - for gradle "it's complicated", since the ndk-build is still not fully supported :(